# Can access MySQL via PHPMyAdmin but not through Command Line

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-16.04

Using the same credentials, and the `root` user having a `localhost` setting. I can login using the same credentials through a phpmyadmin interface. But not through the command line. I've setup the mysql, changed the password and all else. I should be good to go, however I I keep getting

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

In the command line, this seems to also be the case with other as well. So I am not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `sudo mysql -u root` command to access the mysql-server.

If that does not work create a new user through phpmyadmin :

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Then give it all the privileges :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name. * TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

(if you want to give the user access to all the databases, replace db_name with an asterisk (*) )

then flush privileges to reload permissions :

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then try to connect using that user through the command line

```
sudo mysql -u 'username' -p
```

You will be asked to type in the password.